# JSON is Blank while database is not empty

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to create json file using php from the database using localhost. For one table "voteofthanks" its working absolutely fine but writing similar codes for another tables, resulting json file is blank -> results.json. 
[Table for which it is working is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTzQT.png)

and code for creating its json is:

```
<?php 
   define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
   define("DB_USER", "root");
   define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
   define("DB_DATABASE", "StageReady");
   $myConnection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 
   $sqlCommand="SELECT id, content FROM voteofthanks ";
   $posts = array();
   $result=mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
   { 
       $title=$row['id']; 
       $url=$row['content']; 
       $posts[] = array('id'=> $title, 'content'=> $url);

   } 

     $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($posts));
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

and localhost/JSON/results.json is showing up correctly

[table "englishquotes" is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG0ON.png)

now for table englishquotes I write the same code

```
<?php 
   define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
   define("DB_USER", "root");
   define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
   define("DB_DATABASE", "StageReady");
   $myConnection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 
   $sqlCommand="SELECT id, content FROM englishquotes ";
   $posts = array();
   $result=mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
   { 
     $title=$row['id']; 
     $url=$row['content']; 

     $posts[] = array('id'=> $title, 'content'=> $url);

    } 

   $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
   fwrite($fp, json_encode($posts));
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

and I am getting a blank white page on opening localhost/english/results.json

Comment: blank page => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and `mysql_error()` doesn't mix with `mysqli_`. so do `mysqli_error($myConnection)` which is why you're not getting the *real* error.

Comment: Thanku for correcting me @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `htmlspecialchars()` in the line,

```
$posts[] = array('id'=> htmlspecialchars($title), 'content'=> htmlspecialchars($url));
```

Comment: But now I am getting some of the data fields empty and some filled!